# Prove that S[√2] and S[Z] are isomorphic rings.

Tags: ring-theory

Consider the rings
$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{2}]=\{x+\sqrt{2}y:x,y\in \Bbb Z\}$ , since $\Bbb Z$ is a ring and associative with identity.

Define

$$S[\Bbb Z]= \{  \begin{pmatrix}  
a11=a & a12=b \\ a21=2b & a22=a
\end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\Bbb Q):a,b \in \Bbb Z  \} $$

Prove that  $S[\sqrt 2]$ and $S[\Bbb Z]$ are isomorphic rings.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where are you stuck or what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \to S[\mathbb{Z}]$ defined by 
$$f(x+y \sqrt{2})=\begin{pmatrix} x & y\\ 2y &x \end{pmatrix}.$$

It is easy to see that $f$ is linear and that $f(a \cdot b)=f(a) \cdot f(b)$  for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$  so $f$ is an homomorphism.
To prove that $f$ is isomorphism one should to show that

1. $\ker f=0$
2. $Im f=S[\mathbb{Z}]$

Comment: yes but it is not hard..

Comment: @Magdiragdag Guess the inverse ...

Comment: ok, corrected..